# Bitwise left shift behaviour

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Today I was learning about the left shift bit operator (`<<`). As I understand it the left shift bit operator moves bits to the left as specified. And also I know multiply by 2 for shifting. But I am confused, like what exactly is the meaning of "shifting bits" and why does the output differ when value is assigned with a different type?

When I call the function below, it gives output as `System.out.println("b="+b); //Output: 0`

And my question is: how does b become 0 and why is b typecasted?

```
public void leftshiftDemo()
{
    byte a=64,b;
    int i;
    i=a << 2;
    b=(byte)(a<<2);
    System.out.println("i="+i); //Output: 256    i.e 64*2^2
    System.out.println("b="+b); //Output: 0   how & why b is typecasted
}
```

---

**Update** (new doubt):

what does it mean "If you shift a 1 bit into high-order position (Bit 31 or 63), the value will become negative". eg.

```
public void leftshifHighOrder()
{
    int i;
    int num=0xFFFFFFE;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        num=num<<1;
        System.out.println(num);
        /*
         * Output:
         * 536870908
         * 1073741816
         * 2147483632
         * -32   //how this is -ve?
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

Comment: "why is b typecasted" - you tell us! You wrote `(byte) (a << 2)`. Why?

Comment: @Dann Then perhaps the author of that book wanted to demonstrate that, when casting an int to byte, the higher valued bits are just chopped off. That's why b is typecasted. To recognize this, it is enough to recall that 256 = 1 0000 0000 binary, and the cast keeps only the last 8 bits.

Comment: @Ingo   i updated a new doubt above in my question. Please help me

Comment: @Danny, first: I am not "Sir", second: please read the answer from njzk2, he explains it.

Comment: In the future, if you have a new question, don't append it to your current one, but just...ask a new question.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi it is related to this question. so i asked it here. why to spam stackoverflow?

Comment: Asking multiple questions is not "spam", especially when they are in fact distinct questions. [You should try not to ask multiple things in one post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). It fragments the answers and dilutes your problem.

Comment: @Ingo Still i could not  understood my 2nd doubt, plz you explain

Comment: Have you read and understood the linked Wiki article about 2's component representation?

Comment: @Ingo No! But now i read and  got it. `Defination of Java int: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer...` Hence by the 2's complement definition if `1` appears at MSB then the number will be -ve  . Now i think i understood this concept. Am i right?

Comment: @Danny - yes, exactly, nothing agical there. And because this is so, if you shift a 1 bit into the MSG, the result will appear negative.

Comment: @Ingo what does it mean `agical`? you said in your last comment ..

Comment: Sorry, @Danny, should be "magic". Also MSB instead MSG

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When integers are casted to bytes in Java, only the lowest order bits are kept:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T
>   simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number
>   of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of
>   information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause
>   the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input
>   value.

In this case the byte `64` has the following binary representation:

```
01000000
```

The shift operator promotes the value to int:

```
00000000000000000000000001000000
```

then left shifts it by 2 bits:

```
00000000000000000000000100000000
```

We then cast it back into a byte, so we discard all but the last 8 bits:

```
00000000
```

Thus the final byte value is `0`. However, your integer keeps all the bits, so its final value is indeed `256`.

Comment: Thanks donating this answer  !  i am trying to understand what you explained. Can you please give small small example?

Comment: 1 doubt: you said `The shift operator promotes the value to int:

00000000000000000000000001000000` this value came?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but for the purposes of the calculation the value was promoted. In the same way that `int x = 2; int y = (int)(2 * 1.5);` has an implicit promotion to `double`.

Answer (score 2):

In java, ints are signed. To represent that, the [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is used. In this representation, any number that has its high-order bit set to 1 is negative (by definition).

Therefore, when you left-shift a 1 that is on the 31st bit (that is the one before last for an int), it becomes negative.

Comment: Yep, the MSB is the sign bit. However, OP really should have asked a new question.

Comment: in your answer you said `when you left-shift a 1 that is on the 31st bit` ,but what does it mean?

Comment: `0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` that a 1 on the 31st bit. ` << 1` that's left-shift by 1. `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` that's the result. As you can see, the left most bit, which is the most significant bit, is a 1. That implies the value is negative.

Comment: java integer = 32 bits

Comment: Okay i got it. One more small doubt, as you said in your comment `As you can see, the left most bit, which is the most significant bit, is a 1. That implies the value is negative`   How it implies the value is -ve if  appear on the most significant bit?

Comment: i don't know what `-ve` means, but the MSB = 1 implies a 2's complement number is negative *by definition*. See the definition posted earlier.

Comment: Cool! I think now i got it. `int: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer..` Hence by the 2's complement definition if `1` appears at MSb then the number is -ve  . Now i think i understood this concept. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

```
i = a << 2;
```

in memory:

- load a (8 bits) into regitry R1 (32 bits)
- shift registry R1 to the left two position
- assign registry R1 (32 bits) to variable i (32 bits).

`b = (byte)(a << 2);`

in memory:

- load a (8 bits) into regitry R1 (32 bits)
- shift registry R1 to the left two position
- assign registry R1 (32 bits) to variable b (8 bits). <- this is why cast (byte) is necessary and why they get only the last 8 bits of the shift operation

Answer (score 0):

The exact meaning of shifting bits is exactly what it sounds like. :-) You shift them to the left.

> 0011 = 3
>
> 0011 << 1 = 0110
>
> 0110 = 6

Answer (score 0):

You should read about different data types and their ranges in Java.

Let me explain in easy terms.

```
byte a=64,b;
int i;
i=a << 2;
b=(byte)(a<<2);
```

'byte' in Java is signed 2's complement integer. It can store values from -128 to 127 both inclusive. When you do this,

```
i = a << 2;
```

you are left shifting 'a' by 2 bits and the value is supposed to be 64*2*2 = 256. 'i' is of type 'int' and 'int' in Java can represent that value.

When you again left shift and typecast,

```
b=(byte)(a<<2);
```

you keep your lower 8 bits and hence the value is 0.

You can read this for different primitive types in Java.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html